# Title of Sci Fi novel about a musical instrument that was the whole orchestra together in one?

Tags: story-identification

I've asked this before a number of years ago on Amazon somewhere but after looking for over an hour and not finding it I decided to try asking again :)

It was a sci fi novel, all I remember is that there was a musical instrument that was the whole orchestra together in one.

I'm sorry it's so vague, it's been nearly a decade and a half since I read it.

Comment: Is there any other information you can add? For instance do you know any plot details and was it an old book when you read it?

Comment: Who was playing the instrument? Why were they playing the instrument? What makes you think it's science-fiction/fantasy?

Comment: It's not a new book. Almost all of my non-work related reading is and has been sci fi for years..... Helps?

Comment: Karen, I've improved the title of your question so that it's more searchable.

Comment: Karen, you should not edit the title of your question when it's been answered. Instead, upvote the correct answer and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I remembered on my own.....?

Comment: @KarenAdler You can answer your own questions! And it'll be useful for anyone else who was wondering the same as you :)

Answer (score 5):

I got it! [The Memory of Whiteness: A Scientific Romance by Kim Stanley Robinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Memory_of_Whiteness). Thank you for helping trigger my memory. It's an excellent read and highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Could the instrument be the Visi-Sonor from "The Mule" (Foundation and Empire) by Asimov?

Comment: Not Asimov... Have a vague feeling about the word "white" in the title? Maybe? :(

Answer (score 1):

Lloyd Biggle Jr. (who was a musicologist as well as a sf author) wrote a [widely collected](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40844) story "The Tunesmith" (1957), which features an instrument called the multichord.

[Wikipedia says:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd_Biggle,_Jr.)

> His stories frequently used musical and artistic themes. Such notables as songwriter Jimmy Webb and novelist Orson Scott Card have written of the tremendous effect that his early story, "The Tunesmith", had on them in their youth.

Comment: @KarenAdler Feel free to answer your own question separately, so that the system registers your answer (instead of commenting on an unrelated answer!)